# What 3D model formats are supported by ARKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

What 3D model formats are supported by ARKit? 
Does someone know all supported formats for using in ARKit, and which format Xcode can export to use in app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

DAE and OBJ/MTL are *automatically* supported, in the sense that you can just drop the files in the .scnassets folder and it will handle them for you. Personally, I had fewer issues with OBJ/MTL but I'm not well versed in 3D.

The documentation for [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio) states that you can import 3D assets from the following files

> The set of supported formats includes Alembic (.abc), Wavefront Object
>   (.obj), Polygon (.ply), and Standard Tessellation Language (.stl).
>   Additional formats may be supported as well.

I've not worked with this framework though, so can't tell you how well does it work with ARKit.

And you may want to have a look at [AssimpKit](https://github.com/dmsurti/AssimpKit) which allows to export several formats to .scn SceneKit scenes

Comment: You have missed (.scn) file format, One question is what about .fbx file format ? is this supported in ARKit or not ?

Comment: Well, I do mention scn in the last sentence of my answer. I had assumed OP knew about it as it's the default format XCode manages (it may have been a wrong assumption though). Regarding FBX, when I did try it about a year ago it was not directly supported. I tried to use AssimpKit to export it to scn but it did not work well.

Answer (score 13):

##### ARKit, RealityKit, SceneKit

ARKit doesn't read any 3D formats. Only frameworks with rendering engines can do it - SceneKit and RealityKit. These two modules are satellites of ARKit, so they can read in a polygonal geometry in several popular 3D formats. If SceneKit or RealityKit can't read a file, you should convert it into `USDZ` using [usdzconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) Terminal command, Reality Converter, or any online converter. Here's a list of supported formats:

- Collada's Digital Asset Exchange **`.dae`** (SceneKit)
- Pixar's Zipped Universal Scene Description **`.usdz`** (SceneKit and RealityKit)
- Pixar's ASCII Universal Scene Description **`.usda`** (needs conversion)
- Pixar's Binary Universal Scene Description **`.usd`** and **`.usdc`** (needs conversion)
- Reality Composer format **`.rcproject`** (RealityKit in Xcode 14–)
- Reality Composer Pro format **`.realitycomposerpro`** (RealityKit in Xcode 15+)
- Apple's proprietary **`.reality`** format (loads faster in RealityKit)
- Wavefront Object **`.obj`** along with material **`.mtl`** (needs conversion)
- Alembic Interchange File Format **`.abc`** (needs conversion)
- Polygon File Format **`.ply`** (needs conversion)
- Autodesk Filmbox Format **`.fbx`** (needs conversion)
- Graphics Library Transmission Format **`.glTF`** (needs conversion)
- Stereolithography File Format **`.stl`** (needs conversion)
- Native Scene Format **`.scn`** (SceneKit)

##### USDZ loading

You can use USDZ directly in SceneKit and RealityKit and moreover,
you can use it as `MDLAsset`:

```
import RealityKit

var model = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "model.usdz")
```

---

```
import SceneKit

let scene = SCNScene(named: "model.usdz")!
```

---

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO

guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "usdz") 
else { fatalError() }

let mdlAsset = MDLAsset(url: url)
let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: mdlAsset)
```

Answer (score 2):

The full set of file types documented as supported by the Model I/O framework can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391813-canimportfileextension

> The set of supported extensions and formats includes:
>
> - .abc Alembic
> - .usd, .usda, .usdc Universal Scene Description
> - .usdz Universal Scene Description (Mobile)
> - .ply Polygon
> - .obj Wavefront Object
> - .stl Standard Tessellation Language
>
> Additional formats may be supported as well.

It looks like Apple's new preferred file type for ARKit on iOS (as of iOS 12) is their own usdz:

https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/